# macOS: URLResourceValues contain no thumbnails

Tags: swift, thumbnails, foundation

I'm fairly confident that most image files contain thumbnails of a sort because if I import an image file into Filemaker, it offers me a 'thumbnail' property which I can use freely. I thought that with URLResourceValues.thumbnail I had found the relevant resource, but it seems not.

I am getting a valid URL from an NSOpenPanel:

```
let panelResult = openPanel.url
```

but this offers me no opportunity to request a thumbnail. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues) says:
*Only the fields requested by the keys you pass into the URL function to receive this value will be populated. The others will return nil regardless of the underlying property on the file system.*

and this might be the problem, but I cannot request a thumbnail through this route, and if I wanted to create one to set it, I could skip that route and simply create a thumbnail inside my app.

I have tried

```
           if let panelResult = panelResult {   
                do{
                let thumbnailDic = try panelResult.resourceValues(forKeys: [.thumbnailDictionaryKey])
                    print(thumbnailDic)
               }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

which returns

//URLResourceValues(_values: [:], _keys: Set([__C.URLResourceKey(_rawValue: NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey)]))

in other words, an empty dictionary - requesting other keys, like .creationDateKey or .isDirectoryKey give me the correct value, so I don't know whether I can trust 'will return nil'.

I have also attempted to use a FileEnumerator

```
            let resourceKeys : [URLResourceKey] = [.thumbnailDictionaryKey]
            let urlEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: panelResult, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys)
           while let element = urlEnumerator?.nextObject()  {
                if let element = element as? URL {
                    do{
                        let thumbnailDic = try element.resourceValues(forKeys: [.thumbnailDictionaryKey])
                print(thumbnailDic)
                }
                    catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
            }
        }
```

but that suffers from the same problem: using other keys, I can retrieve their values, using .thumbnailDictionaryKey, I get an empty dictionary.

So does anyone have any insights on what I must do to ensure the system populates the URLResourceValues.thumbnail property, respectively how I gain access to it?

I'm not overly fussed about the size/quality/origin of thumbnails, I just want a no-hassle way of previewing images in my app.

Comment: You can use NSWorkspace to get a file icon.

Comment: Firstly, this seems to be the file icon, rather than an thumbnail, and second, can you specify what kind of path this expects? NSOpenPanel's filepath has been deprecated forever, and openPanel.url.absoluteString 'is not a full path', apparently.

Comment: The correct path is openPanel.url.path, of course; which still does not get me a thumbnail. (The documentation says they should be generated automatically on macOS; this is not happening.)